# Odoo POSBOX assign static IP address

Tags: static, raspberry-pi, odoo-8, dhcp

I'm trying to assign a static ip address to my odoo posbox installed on a raspberry pi. I tried editing the **/etc/dhcpcd.conf** file by adding

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.30/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Also tried editing the **/etc/network/interfaces** file as so,

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Both solutions worked, but whenever I reboot my pc the dhcpcd assigns a new ip address. Tried to disable this:

> update-rc.d -f dhcpd remove

Answer (score 0):

I am also working in POS Box but I had no problem in dynamic IP although you can refer to the following link. It might be useful because this question is already asked in odoo community.

[This is odoo community link where this question has been asked.](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/posbox-static-ip-address-91966)

Apart from that this link may be helpful to you too.

[This link is of github document](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3156)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot or problems with dynamic IPs with POSBOX.

You have to edit the IMG, for this follow this steps:

```
https://stefanoprenna.com/blog/2014/09/22/tutorial-how-to-mount-raw-images-img-images-on-linux/
```

Afterwards, when you have mounted the IMG, edit the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Umount the IMG, then burn it as usual, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo filesystem is mounted in readonly mode. So before making changes you shuold run

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
sudo mount -o remount,rw /root_bypass_ramdisks
```

to put it in writable mode

Then you can edit dhcpcd.conf in the permanent position:

```
nano /root_bypass_ramdisks/etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

and add settings according to your network:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.30/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Pay attention to put the `/root_bypass_ramdisks` prefix before normal root position

This way your changes wil be permanent also after reboot

[reference](https://odootips.com/ip-est%C3%A1tica-en-posbox-8843a763216)